# The history of the NULL pointer

Tags: c

As we know, in C to dereference a null pointer is undefined behaviour. From what I understand, the PDP-7 and the PDP-11 both have ordinary memory that can be written to and read from at address 0.

On the PDP-11, that address is part of a memory region used to specify `EMT` and `TRAP` vectors. An operating system probably needs to be able to initialise these to the entry point of device drivers or whatever. And depending on model and configuration, writing to this memory location might cause a trap -- but the same goes for all other memory locations. So location 0 is not unique in that respect on this platform.

From what I can tell, the PDP-7 had ordinary memory at that address, just as many other machines do. But I understand that UB is very useful to compilers which need to be able to not guarantee a particular behaviour so that a particular architecture can be targeted easily.

So my question is what led some C standard to treat the NULL pointer differently from any other pointer? Did K&R want to target an exotic architecture or something?

Comment: Your question seems to assume that NULL is 0x00000000.  That was not always the case.  On various C compilers it was 0xFFFFFFFF or even 0xDEADBEEF.  It was always bad practice to assume NULL was zero.

Comment: @Chenmunka WHAT?! I can picture that 0xFFFFFFFF might make sense. From what I understand, the 8086 prefers that for a falsey value. But 0xdeadbeef is completely unexpected (to me).

Comment: DEADBEEF originated on IBM mainframes as a code for an invalid value, but it did spread to other systems.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2907262/2870922 for a little information.

Comment: DEADBEEF is a common 'joke' calue to denote special situations. It works fine in hex dumps, usually on big endian machines. Often data structures start with link pointers, DEADBEEF instead of 00000000 also made clear that it's on purpose, as a value of 00000000 (or FFFFFFFF) could also originate in a previous clearing of the memory area.

Comment: @Chenmunka Sorry, it didn't came from Mainframes, but the small stuff (IBM terminology Midrange), systems in the line of /3 to AS400. Mainframes had their own ways.

Comment: @Raffzahn:  Yes, but I always thought of those machines as mainframes.  I can see this becoming a question in its own right.

Comment: @Chenmunka Ok, I see. Well, being in contact to /370ish machines since the late 1970, I developed a quite fundamentalist view here. Only /370 and alike machnes are mainframe. everything else is a toy, made for department use where business suits try to emulate real IT. A midrange system and it's users where in the old days to us about the same as some loony trying to run a company on Excel sheets and Word-macros. The only exception here are eventually scientific machines (CDC/Cray/etc.). While not being able to do real work, they *do* have some feats.

Comment: Most CPUs treat 0 different from every other number via a zero flag in their status register.  PDP-11 memory loads and math operations do an implicit comparison to zero so you could branch without an explicit comparison.  c.f. zero-terminated strings and 0/everything else booleans.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock except that the equation of 0/false/nil is inherited from BCPL, and not made to fit the PDP11. Also, 'many' is missleading and arbitary, as there as as well 'many' CPUs checking for zero during load - including such without a zero flag (Did I mention the /370?).

Comment: @Chenmunka I have never worked with a C compiler where the null pointer was anything other than 0. In fact, in olden days `NULL` was a macro that was essentially `0`

Comment: @JeremyP: The Standard requires that conversion of an integer literal zero to a pointer type yield the bit pattern an implementation uses for a null pointer.

Comment: @Chenmunka: While in theory a C compiler could use a bit pattern other than 0 for NULL, I'm not aware of any C compiler that does -- do you know of one?  POSIX additionally requires that using memset to 0 memory containing any pointers also sets those pointers to NULL, which pretty much requires using a 0 bit pattern for NULL.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The definition of `NULL` is a syntactic crutch to allow a programmer a clear expression that a pointer is, at certain times, pointing nowhere. It's meant for readability - and with increased compiler bloat even for automated checks.

On a hardware level there is no such thing. A pointer is a word, and a word always holds a valid number. So by convention zero was chosen - it could have been any other. Like `-1` for example. Selecting 0 offered the advantage that a simple `if(pointer)` could be used to check if it's a valid pointer (or more correct, *not* `0`).

> So my question is what led some C standard to treat the NULL pointer differently from any other pointer?

C also doesn't treat `NULL` different from any other pointer. The C library in contrast does, but not because of `NULL`, but rather as its (runtime) value of `0` will make some functions fail, when used as input.

> Did K&R want to target an exotic architecture or something?

No. It's a concept needed from a pure software engineering point of view. Having a syntactic construct to handle uninitialized pointers improves readability and possibly enables further checks.

---

**Now, for the historic part**, `NULL` is, like the related handling of `TRUE`/`FALSE` inherited from BCPL (through B). Just here it was called `nil`.

---

Even with that little historic bit, I'm not sure if Retrocomputing is the right place to ask for this, as it's about a basic concept in software engineering and not anything burdened with historic implication. So a quick search in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128327/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pointer-pointing-to-0x0-location-and-a-pointer) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296865/2973400) shows that this question has been asked many times. It's something people always stumble on, isn't it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72809/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-the-history-of-the-null-pointer).

Comment: A `NULL` pointer does not need store the number `0`. The C standard says that converting the integer `0` to a pointer will produce a `NULL` pointer. That's why `memset()` for `0` initialization is only safe to use with integers. When you put pointer inside an `if`, the pointer is converted to an integer - that's why you can use it in an `if` expression.

Comment: I've never heard of a NULL pointer referred to as a VOID pointer. A void pointer (aka a value with type `void*`) is a pointer that doesn't have a concrete type, not one that is null.

Comment: The C standard does treat null pointer differently form any other pointer. E.g. see 6.3.2.3/3: _An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function._

Comment: Erm, @Ruslan, there isno 6.3.2.3 in _'The C Programming Language'_ could you maybe refer to something not related here?

Comment: @Raffzahn The cited sentence is in the C99 standard - not in the K&R book.

Comment: I was citing the final draft of the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard AKA C11: [version N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), but the reference is also valid for C99 (and in C90 it's 6.2.2.3).

Comment: @martinkunev: "The C standard says that converting the integer 0 to a pointer will produce a NULL pointer."  No, only integral constants, not values of integer variables.  "When you put pointer inside an if, the pointer is converted to an integer"  No, the `if` statement controlling expression is compared against 0.  And the conversion turns the integral constant zero into a null pointer value -- the pointer is not turned into an integer.

Comment: @Raffzahn K&R first edition "C guarantees that no pointer that validly points at data will contain zero" - therefore the NULL pointer IS treated specially by the language, both historically and in modern times..

Comment: @Muzer Mind to add a ceckable reference  (book, page), as I can't find that sentence in my copy. Beside the fact that I wouldn't know an way of C to ensure this concept - that's why there is so often the term 'meaningful' used. C doesn't have any a priori protection agains pointers pointing anywhere, including address zero.

Comment: @Raffzahn Chapter 5 page 97. Found on archive.org https://ia801303.us.archive.org/1/items/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20%5BUA-07%5D.pdf . Again, the modern interpretation is that a pointer could point to the raw address 0 but if so, the compiler would have to choose another representation for a NULL pointer, and guarantee that when a pointer is compared against literal 0 that it's actually compared against this other representation. However you look at it, this is special treatment for NULL pointers.

Comment: @Muzer I still can't see any special treatment here. And there has never been one. If you want, just vome over and we fire one of my PDPs up with a contemporaty (1978) System and you'll notice that one can easy assign 0 to a pointer and use it to access data. You're making assumptions that simply aren't tru. especiylly not back then.

Comment: @Raffzahn Just because it works doesn't mean it's correct C. You can do loads of things on a modern C compiler that work, but they're undefined behaviour. Clearly this was true even back then, though obviously the concepts of "undefined behaviour" weren't, themselves, rigorously defined.

Comment: @Muzer Aeh, are youswitching arguments on the fly? Wasn't your point thet the compiler **guarantees** that it will not  happen? LOL

Comment: @Raffzahn no, the C standard, including the less formal definition given by K&R, guarantees it. If you're accessing address 0 by doing char *someptr = 0; and are then able to read to/write from it, either you or your compiler are doing it wrong, by the letter of the K&R book as well as later standards. Either you shouldn't be doing that and you're relying on an implementation detail that goes against the standard, or your compiler is doing it wrong in not giving you a more compliant way of accessing address 0 (assuming it was the compiler's goal to let you do so).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72913/discussion-between-raffzahn-and-muzer).

Comment: @Muzer: There's another possibility: while an implementation can't put any "normal" C object at the address represented by a null pointer, an implementation might store something else there, and allow the use of null pointers to access it.  For example, in large mode 8086 with high memory support, the only way to access the divide-overflow interrupt vector is to use a pointer whose segment and offset portions are both zero, so the easiest way for a C compiler on that platform to allow code to configure that interrupt is by making a write to `*(void(**)())0` act as a write to that address.

Answer (score 22):

The important thing you may be missing is that a null pointer in C is not required by the standard to have the same binary representation as the number zero. It is still a "normal" pointer, but it points to a special location that the program is not allowed to use.

The integer constant `0` is turned into `nullptr` when used as a pointer. Similarly, `0` will become `0.0` when used in floating-point calculations, or `false` in boolean operations. Coercions are not just one-way: `if(ptr)` will convert a pointer into a boolean which indicates whether the pointer is not null. All of these conversions serve to avoid requiring that a null pointer shares the same representation as zero.

Most machines represent integer zero as all-bits-zero and comparisons against that are particularly cheap, so it is worthwhile to arrange things so that sentinel values such as null pointers and end-of-string markers are all-bits-zero, and also that `+0.0` and `false` are also all-bits-zero.

There is some subtlety in C in that a literal `0` is converted into `nullptr`, whereas casting an integer that happens to be zero into a pointer will produce a pointer to location zero. Because they are the same thing on modern platforms, a whole class of potential bugs go away.

Comment: @Wilson I informally described the C standard. My copy is marked ISO/IEC 9899 and pointers are discussed in section 6.3.2.3. Note what is *not* said there.

Comment: I think you meant "a null pointer" where you wrote `nullptr` - the latter is a C++ keyword, but not defined in C.

Comment: Converting an integer expression that evaluates to zero -- and that is not an integer constant expression -- to a pointer type produces implementation-defined behavior, and carries a bunch of caveats.  This *might* yield a pointer to address 0, or it might not.

Comment: You seem to be describing C++. There is no `nullptr` in C. Also, `if` works with integers. If you put a pointer inside, it is converted to an integer (not to a boolean).

Comment: @martinkunev: A pointer inside used as an `if` or `while` condition will tested to see if it's not equal to a null pointer.  There is no requirement that conversion of a null pointer to an integer must yield zero, but if `p` is null, `if (p)` will treat `p` as a false condition even if `(uintptr)p` would be a non-zero value.

Answer (score 14):

Another relevant historical tidbit: You may have noticed that the values chosen for NULL - i.e 0xFFFFFFFF and 0xDEADBEEF - *are both odd-valued addresses*.  Most architectures (certainly most at the time Unix was created) did not implement addressing down to the individual byte; they were only able to address words of two or four bytes - that is, only even-valued addresses were legal.  By choosing an odd-valued address for the value of NULL, the C compiler and runtime system ensured that any attempt to actually dereference NULL would immediately trap to the OS; that is why the usual error for dereferencing NULL on Unix is 'Segmentation Violation'.

Comment: On many systems you get `SIGBUS` (Bus error) for presenting an unaligned address - usually `SIGSEGV` is for any access to memory not mapped for the process.

Comment: Apart from that final error, addressed in @TobySpeight's comment, this answer is correct. It brings something up that not many previous answers have. Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. You might find the [tour] interesting.

Comment: You get SIGSEGV for NULL dereference on modern Unix systems (including ones where alignment is required) because the zero page of virtual address space is not mapped.  Most systems do use `0` as the run-time bit-pattern for `NULL`.

Comment: You're conflating word-addressable memory (you *can't* reference the individual bytes of a word with single-byte load/store) with alignment-required for word loads, but still having byte-addressable memory.  (So two adjacent 4-byte words have a difference of 4 in address.  Even if ([like on early Alpha AXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory)) there aren't byte load/store instructions.  Many RISC machines require alignment for word loads, but still *have* byte loads.  So yes, a NULL deref with a word load might SIGBUS.

Answer (score 8):

Tony Hoare somewhat-famously in 2009 said this:

> I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965. At that time, I was designing the first comprehensive type system for references in an object oriented language (ALGOL W). My goal was to ensure that all use of references should be absolutely safe, with checking performed automatically by the compiler. But I couldn't resist the temptation to put in a null reference, simply because it was so easy to implement. This has led to innumerable errors, vulnerabilities, and system crashes, which have probably caused a billion dollars of pain and damage in the last forty years.

While I don't have any specific citations, I suspect that C was influenced by ALGOL, or just made the same decision separately since having a specific value to represent "not a valid reference" was an easy and useful thing to do. It wasn't so much about "how to point to a specific part in memory that's named 'zero'" as much as "we need to define a way to indicate that a pointer is not currently valid", particularly as a sentinel value. Given the constraints of computers at that time, it seemed a reasonable thing to do. So, one just creates a value called "NULL" which can be assigned to any pointer type, and there you have it.

Comment: I see no reasonable basis for regarding null as a mistake.  It's often necessary to create an array of pointers and then read out some values before all values have been written.  Having non-written items read out as null is better than any other alternative unless one has separate syntax for "read out and trap if null" and "read value without trapping even if null".  The biggest problem with null is that many language implementations do not adequately trap for it.

Comment: Well, @supercat, your argument is with Tony Hoare, not with Peter, who's just quoting here.  For a (non-retro) way to tame NULL, one worthwhile approach is the Null Object design pattern.  It's still hard to enforce in C-family languages, where we can point to NULL or to deallocated memory (C++ references don't quite fit, as they aren't reseatable).

Comment: Yes, I wasn't trying to present an opinion on the usefulness of NULL so much as present the little bit of the history that I'd heard of, that it was added to ALGOL because it was easy and seemed useful. Especially as the question was looking for the influences that led to C having NULL as a concept, I thought the quote might shed some light on it.

Comment: @supercat So you *do* see a reasonable basis for regarding null as a mistake after all. See your last sentence and look out for adequately trapping null values in ALGOL. :-)

Comment: @BlackJack: From what I understand, the choice Hoare faced was between having pointers only be usable as values if they identify valid storage, or having a default pointer value which cannot be dereferenced but can be treated as a value.  Given those choices, the former is not by any stretch of the imagination a "mistake".  Having implementations trap attempts to dereference null pointers *or apply a non-zero displacement* would have been reasonably practical, and if languages had routinely included features to do so, CPUs could have added instructions to assist with the latter part of that.

Comment: @supercat NULL's problem is that a) it is one level so in said array you cannot distinguish between 'element is not set' and 'element is set but it is NULL which means something different' and b) it can appear anywhere so you cannot enforce that it is not present. I don't think in 1965 NULL was necessary a mistake. In 2018 when we can and do have things like Optional, which even in some languages are just nullable pointers for one level, they probably should not be used outside limited circumstances.

Comment: When I first started using Unix, I was told to beware of AIX and HPUX.  They allowed the user to write to wherever NULL pointed to and not crash.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: If one has reads an unwritten element from a partially-written array of pointers, there are three main choices: 1. Trap immediately; 2. Yield a meaningless pointer that may be indistinguishable from a valid one; 3. Yield a pointer that is recognizably invalid.  The only advantage of #2 is that it might be faster.  Advantage #1 is sometimes better, but makes it very difficult for code to copy a partially-written portion of one array to another array if it doesn't know which parts have been written.  Using approach #3 the code doesn't need to know or care about that.

Comment: @supercat Note that this is (kind of) what Optional/Some/... does... except it is explicit and allows nesting. The main problem with NULL is that it can appear anywhere and you cannot specify easily that argument cannot be non-NULL. However often using such arguments is UB and might result in something else than trap representation (C/C++) or require checking every time (Java). A better approach seems to be not to have NULL by default and 'opt-in' by annotations. Or in 2018 use a special type and allow compiler to optimize indirection out.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: Use of an `optional` approach in a way that supports nesting often requires that each array element separately record whether or not it is a valid value, and what its value is (if valid).  This is more expensive than simply storing a pointer which has a reserved bit pattern to indicate that it is invalid.  A good approach for some usage scenarios might be to have an array type which stores the "used length" separately from the size, and say that code wanting to extend an array must specify the value(s) to go in the new slot(s).  That wouldn't work for all use cases...

Comment: ...but would handle many.  Even something like a generic hash table could be accommodated by having data items stored in an array whose elements are filled sequentially, and then having a hash map hold indices into that array.  I don't know any languages that handle arrays in that fashion, but maybe some do.

Answer (score 5):

> As we know, in C to dereference a null pointer is undefined behaviour.

It is now, but the PDP-11 was an obsolete architecture before the first standard C was published. At the time when the PDP-11was current hardware, the only thing close to a standard was *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie (henceforth referred to as K&R).

The null pointer wasn't a formal a concept back then and pointers were generally considered to be interchangeable with `int`s although that wasn't always the case (a primary source of pain for portability). A pointer whose value was 0 was considered special and there was a macro `NULL` whose definition was something like `((char *) 0)`. Note that K&R C has no `void` type.

Dereferencing a null pointer is only designated as  undefined behaviour so that the compiler doesn't have add a check to every dereference to make sure the pointer is not null. It's perfectly acceptable for your architecture to have that work as with any other address. In fact, if your program crashes with a `SIGSEGV` when you dereference a null pointer, it is not because the compiler put a check in but because your operating system has made it illegal for user space programs to access the location.

So an operating system writer could set up the PDP-11 trap vector table in C as long as he is confident that the compiler will treat address 0 like any other. Since, in early versions of Unix the OS team and the compiler team overlapped, this was obviously not an issue.

> So my question is what led some C standard to treat the NULL pointer differently from any other pointer? Did K&R want to target an exotic architecture or something?

No. The C standard came a decade after C and Unix were written. By this time it was obvious that null pointers were causing issues.

**Edit**

OK, so I had a look at my copy of *The C Programming Language* (first edition) and it turns out that I was wrong. On page 97 we have (in relation to implementing a custom allocator)

> C guarantees that no pointer that validly points at data will contain zero, so a return value of zero can be used to signify an abnormal event.

On page 190

> A pointer may be compared to an integer but the result is machine dependent unless the integer is the constant 0. A pointer to which 0 has been assigned is guaranteed not to point to any object, and will appear to be equal to 0; in **conventional usage**, such a pointer is considered to be null.

[my emphasis]

Setting up an interrupt table for an operating system would not be considered conventional usage.

Answer (score 4):

For the PDP-11, you're thinking of physical address 0 for interrupt vectors. Logical address 0 in a user program just contains the first bytes of program code, i.e. the primary entry point ("start" from crt0.s). On a default executable, nothing stops you from reading it or writing to it, though if you write after the address returned to by main, you're gonna have a bad time. With `ld -n`, it'll be read-only and attempting to write it will cause `SIGSEGV`.

So in that sense, a null pointer and a pointer to the "start" routine were identical, but it wasn't actually possible to reference assembly routines that did not begin with underscores from C. The PDP-11 probably wasn't the only architecture to put machine code (particularly startup code) that was not a valid C function at the zero address... it's a natural place to begin execution at, it wasn't something you could intentionally make a C pointer to, and it's something you need anyway.

The other solution is just to waste some small amount of space ensuring that that address is not used for anything. On "split I/D" executables on the PDP-11, data address 0 contains a zero explicitly put there for that purpose in crt0.s - in my test program, this was followed immediately by character data for the string literals I used with printf. (As has been pointed out, this could be at any address, not necessarily 0.)

Answer (score 2):

C treats NULL differently because it is undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour is very different to implementation defined behaviour. Implementation-defined behaviour can simplify portability by allowing different implementations to make different choices (for example, different platforms have different native integer representations).

Undefined behaviour is only partly related to portability - there's no requirement that undefined behaviour be consistent, even on the same platform (so even if C had only targetted a single platform, it may still have included undefined behaviour). In addition to the portability gains,  undefined behaviour allows implementations to emit simpler or faster code, by making error handling optional for certain error conditions. To quote the C rationale document (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior#answer-14487077)):

> The terms *unspecified* behavior, *undefined* behavior, and *implementation-defined* behavior are used to categorize the result of writing programs whose properties the Standard does not, or cannot, completely describe. The goal of adopting this categorization is to allow a certain variety among implementations which permits quality of implementation to be an active force in the marketplace as well as to allow certain popular extensions, without removing the cachet of conformance to the Standard. Appendix F to the Standard catalogs those behaviors which fall into one of these three categories.
>
> *Unspecified behavior* gives the implementor some latitude in translating programs. This latitude does not extend as far as failing to translate the program.
>
> *Undefined behavior* gives the implementor license not to catch certain program errors that are difficult to diagnose. It also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior.
>
> *Implementation-defined behavior* gives an implementor the freedom to choose the appropriate approach, but requires that this choice be explained to the user. Behaviors designated as implementation-defined are generally those in which a user could make meaningful coding decisions based on the implementation definition. Implementors should bear in mind this criterion when deciding how extensive an implementation definition ought to be. As with unspecified behavior, simply failing to translate the source containing the implementation-defined behavior is not an adequate response.

Comment: The intended purpose was portability and efficiency of "straightforward" code. The authors of the C89 Rationale clearly intended that an expression like `(ushort1 * ushort2) & 0xFFFF` consistently yield the lower 16 bits of the result on modern implementations (they cite the behavior of "most current implementations" in such cases as part of the reason for making `unsigned short` promote to `int` when the latter is a larger type). I've seen no evidence that the authors of the Standard intended to invite compilers to assume that `ushort1 <= 2147483647/ushort2` in such cases.

Comment: I've updated my commentary to be closer to the meaning of the rationale document. You're right that aggressive compiler optimisation is a relatively recent development, and it was misleading to suggest it's what the authors intended. Do you reckon I should strip the answer back to just the rationale document? Including that was my main aim anyway.

Comment: I think it may be worthwhile to mention that the rationale identifies some typical ways implementations may act in cases where the Standard imposes no requirements; it does not offer any guidance as to when quality implementations should seek to behave in the manners described.  On some implementations, an attempted null access would access whatever happened to be at address zero (which might on a few occasions be useful, e.g. if 8086 code needs to set the divide-by-zero interrupt vector which is located there).  On others, it would trap.  Today, it may negate laws of time and causality.