# How widely was 0xDEADBEEF used as a placeholder, invalid value?

Tags: history, ibm, dec

Inspired by some comments on the question ["*The history of the NULL pointer*"](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5671/276):-

There was a practice in the '70s to use the hexadecimal code `0xDEADBEEF` to indicate an invalid value.  This could be to fill memory that was freed after a previous allocation, as the value of `NULL` in C, or as an inaccessible address.

The use of DEADBEEF is said to have originated on IBM midrange machines, as an easily identifiable error code when looking at a hex dump.  My experience of it is on VMS on DEC Vax machines, it allegedly was used on Apple Macs and the Commodore Amiga.  However, I haven't encountered it in use for several years.

Quick searching throws up differing and contradictory stories as to its spread and usage, so...

Did IBM system engineers change jobs and take DEADBEEF with them as a code in other systems?

Comment: It’s used quite a bit in the Linux kernel: `git grep -i deadbeef | wc -l` prints 404. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) it’s also used to mark freed memory in Solaris.

Comment: I realy can't add hard facts here, just hearsay - and an experiance that all machines I fould it where big endian types. Personally I'd put its usage more into the region of the 80s desprite being developed in the 70s, as it is based on the existence 32 bit pointers.

Comment: BTW: Love the question, even though I have no answer.

Comment: From what I remember, it's used in a JVM for something internal like the type tag on a certain object or something.

Comment: Note than an [Ox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ox) is also of species of bovine cattle.

Comment: @Chenmunka, is your question about where the value is used nowadays, or about its history?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907262/what-does-dead-beef-mean - Also has some usages

Comment: FWIW, the Dalvik VM on Android dereferenced 0xdeadd00d and 0xdeadbaad to cause specific crash signatures when internal problems were detected. That was a play on 0xdeadbeef. (This causes a segmentation fault on 32-bit Android because 0xdead**** is an address in Linux kernel space that user-space code can't write to.)

Comment: However, I haven't encountered it in use for several years.<-- I've seen it used in production code circa 2005.

Comment: It's not an answer because the question is "how widely used *was*" rather than *is* but a quick in-code search on GitHub — https://github.com/search?q=0xdeadbeef&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93 — provides 2,705,863 usages. Huge numbers of duplicates because that double(/triple/etc) counts forks and the like but it's clearly there in QEMU, GDB binutils and Python.

Comment: @StephenKitt - I can attest to the solaris connection, as that's where I first encountered it.  It's also used for the same purposes in some debug builds of glibc (I don't know whether this information is still current, however, as most of my low-level work tends to be in other environments, these days...).

Comment: I still use it for some things today.  Like tripping a logic analyzer on a data corruption/miscompare issue when bringing up new hardware.  It's just a value, like any other hex sequence you might use. There are a lot of english words that can be spelled with just hex and a loose interpretation of 0, 1, etc.

Comment: I seem to remember that certain HP's MPE machines would display F0FF as a status....

Comment: Since the late 70s, I have been using DEADBEEF, 00C0FFEE, F00D5AFE and all sorts of words that I could make up with 1 as I, 2 as Z, 5 as S, 6 as G.  5AFEBEEF was a favourite during the BSE scare.  In those days, you just made up stuff to keep the debuggers and bug reporters amused.  I've never seen it in any production code except the stuff I write.  Brings a smile to your face when reading **there is C0FFEE is coming through the network** or **5AFE BEEF is appearing all over the screen**.  If someone is using a logic analyser it would be the AA/55 or CC/33: nice, easily recognizable patterns.

Comment: @cup, just remember 0xDECAFBAD.

Comment: A games company I worked at in the early 2000s used it when developing memory systems on Nintendo handhelds.

Comment: Ref: [Magic Number - Debug Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values).

Comment: I was never an IBM programmer and I've used 0xDEADBEEF in my career stretching from the 90's till now.

Answer (score 25):

It can be found in implementations of `zfs` such as OpenZFS, inherited from the Solaris Kernel Memory C header file:

https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/sys/kmem_impl.h line 80

```
#define KMEM_FREE_PATTERN       0xdeadbeefdeadbeefULL
```

Quote from the `magic number` wiki page:

> "Dead beef", Famously used on IBM systems such as the RS/6000, also used in the classic Mac OS operating systems, OPENSTEP Enterprise, and the Commodore Amiga. On Sun Microsystems' Solaris, marks freed kernel memory (KMEM_FREE_PATTERN)

Answer (score 16):

In a similar vein, Algol-68R on ICL 1900 (a 24-bit machine) initialized memory to -6815700, which when displayed as text (four 6-bit characters), spelled 'F00L', as well as possessing numerous other virtues.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68-R#F00L

Comment: I remember that - mainly used to show that the memory was uninitialized.  Always got lots of F00Ls when the program crashed.

Comment: That is a FourCC code. Although the term was probably not coined back then.

Comment: Myrias, a parallel processor company I worked for in the 80's, used 0x4E4F4E4F for uninitialized memory.   Looking out for NONO's in data was a common activity :-)

Answer (score 5):

I've been working on IBM CICS transaction system and VSE operating system in the middle '80s and in the system dumps (I can't really remember if VSE's or CICS's) programmers put what they called "eyecatchers". The most famous one was really 0xDEADBEEF.
I'm pretty sure I've seen and used it a couple of times... it helped you spot the control block in the dump page and from there you could easily position to the offset you needed to check. Remember that dumps, at those times, were pack of printed paper weighing some Kg. I tried to search for this specific eyecatcher on the net but could not find anything related... maybe some old (wiser) IBMer could remember if it was CICS or VSE!

Answer (score 2):

[HETE 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HETE_2) used DEADBEEF as padding in the downlink, together with BABECAFE as packet sync.